# What does "common interface" mean in OOP?

Tags: object-oriented

I have seen the term "common interface" used a lot while reading books about OOP.

For example, the book *The Essence of Object-Oriented Programming with Java and UML* says the following:

> Abstract classes usually define a common interface for subclasses by
> specifying methods that all subclasses must override and define

---

My understanding of the term "common interface" is the following:

Assume that we have a superclass (or an `interface` or an `abstract class`) called `Animal` and two subclasses called `Dog` and `Cat`, and `Animal` have two virtual methods called `makeSound()` and `move()`.

Now the common interface would be composed of two methods which are `Animal.makeSound()` and `Animal.move()`.

Assume that we have the following code:

```
Animal animal1 = new Dog();
animal1.makeSound();
animal1.move();

animal1 = new Cat();
animal1.makeSound();
animal1.move();
```

The explanation of the above code is the following:

`Animal animal1 = new Dog()` creates an `Animal` common interface and associate a `Dog` object with it:

[image]

`animal1.makeSound()` sends an `Animal.makeSound()` message to the common interface, and then the common interface sends a `Dog.makeSound()` message to the `Dog` object:

[image]

Same thing happens in the case of `animal1.move()` (which is the `Animal.move()` message is sent to the common interface, etc.).

`animal1 = new Cat()` removes the `Dog` object from the common interface, and associate a `Cat` object with the common interface:

[image]

`animal1.makeSound()` sends an `Animal.makeSound()` message to the common interface, and then the common interface sends a `Cat.makeSound()` message to the `Cat` object:

[image]

Same thing happens in the case of `animal1.move()` (which is the `Animal.move()` message is sent to the common interface, etc.).

Am I correct in my understanding?

---

**Edit:**

The `Animal` common interface in my diagram is not an object, but rather it is the virtual methods (or I guess I can call them the "message handlers") that receive the `Animal.makeSound()` and `Animal.move()` messages and then send the appropriate messages to the associated subclass object.

Comment: `The Animal common interface in my diagram is not an object, but rather it is the virtual methods (or I guess I can call them the "message handlers") that receive the Animal.makeSound() and Animal.move() messages and then send the appropriate messages to the associated subclass object. Does this make my diagram correct now?` Due to this comment, I considered removing my answer because I find a meaningful difference between the question  *What does “common interface” mean in OOP?* and *Ho are interface calls managed in runtime by the JVM*.

Comment: That said, I would ask you to edit the question so it's clear what of the two things you are asking about. T think the answers bellow illustrate what "common interface" use to mean for many of us. If that's not the point of the question and you are only interested in how Java manage this internally, I think you might be interested in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423968/how-are-java-interfaces-implemented-internally-vtables)

Comment: Looks like the link I shared might help you out to find the answer. Note that the link in the checked answer is in reference to OpenJDK. I assume the answer may differ from JVM to JVM

Answer (score 8):

An interface is not a separate entity or object - an interface is just a *characteristic* (or set of characteristics) of an object.    Specifically characteristics which describe how to use/interact with an object.

The term "common interface" is a way of describing the fact that `Dog` and `Cat` happen to share some of the same characteristics, and that these shared characteristics can allow these to be used interchangeably in code.   *(provided that there are no `Dog`-specific or `Cat`-specific characteristics involved)*.

To shift to another very simple example, most programming languages have data types called `int` and `double` - these nearly always share a common interface because they can both be used with the 'BODMAS' arithmetic operators despite the fact that integer representation and floating-point representation work very differently to each other.

In the given example of `animal1.move()`,  `animal1` is just a plain variable (i.e. a **name**) - it has no behaviour of its own.   It's a simple programming language construct which acts as a name/alias for an object, and which enables a programmer to write code that uses/interacts with an object

- if the `animal1` variable is an alias to a `Dog` object, then `animal1.move()` sends a `move()` message directly to that `Dog` object.
- if the `animal1` variable is an alias to a `Cat` object, then `animal1.move()` sends a `move()` message directly to that `Cat` object.

A better analogy for the term *interface* could be when thinking about how a human interacts with a car while they are sitting in the driver's seat.    From a driver's point of view, all cars have a common interface for someone driving the car:

- A steering wheel
- Accelerator pedal
- Brake pedal
- Hazard Lights
- Indicators

These are all characteristics of any car, however, any individual car will always have their own Steering wheel, pedals, lights, etc.

The term "common interface" is conceptual rather than physical (the interface isn't separate from the object, it is part of the object) - the common interface of a car means that any qualified driver of one car is able to seamlessly take control over any other car without needing to adapt their understanding of how to drive.    The rules and actions involved in driving one car do not change when switching to a different car.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you wouldn't even need an object to have an interface, if you look outside OOP. Still, a good explanation.

Comment: You said: *"if the animal1 variable is an alias to a Dog object, then animal1.move() sends a move() message directly to that Dog object"* and *"if the animal1 variable is an alias to a Cat object, then animal1.move() sends a move() message directly to that Cat object"*, by *"move() message"*, do you mean `Animal.move()` message? and so the whole point of `Dog` and `Cat` implementing an `interface` (or overriding the virtual methods of a superclass) is to be able to respond to the same messages (in this case `Animal.makeSound` and `Animal.move()`)?

Comment: @Tom Not quite; there isn't an `Animal.move()` message, and `Animal` isn't an object. But more importantly, `Animal` exists to describe the how an object can be used - it doesn't affect what `Dog` or `Cat` can do.    It just allows those objects to be used interchangeably.    The *message* is simply just `move()` (i.e. the thing on the right-hand-side of the dot `.`). `Dog` and `Cat` objects could still handle `move()` without the interface, but without a common interface, sending a message would require explicit knowledge of whether the object is a `Dog` or `Cat`.

Comment: *"The message is simply just move()"* do you mean that both `Cat` and `Dog` objects can receive the same message `move()`? because I remember reading that even though objects of different types (for example: `Cat` and `Dog` objects) can receive some message, like `move()` (for example: `cat1.move()` and `dog1.move()`), in reality the `move()` message that is being sent to the `Cat` objects is different from the `move()` message that is being sent to the `Dog` objects, it's just that both messages have the same name (which is `move()`).

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure of the context of what you read so I can't comment on what that means.  However, the point of a common interface is for `Cat` and `Dog` objects to be used interchangeably, which can only work if both are capable of receiving exactly the same message.    To put it another way, if they were different messages, then the interface wouldn't be common, and the code which uses those objects would need to select a different message to send depending upon the target object's type - e.g. `if animal1 is Dog` or `if animal1 is Cat`.

Comment: I don't think I explained accurately what I meant in my comments, but I think that you still managed to answer a lot of my questions in your last comment. What I meant was that when `Cat` and `Dog` are standalone classes (i.e. they don't inherit from `Animal`), then when you do `cat1.move()` and `dog1.move()`, the `move()` message that `cat1.move()` sends is different than the `move()` message that `dog1.move()` sends (even though both messages have the same name, which is `move()`)...

Comment: ...so to distinguish between these two `move()` messages, I said in a previous comment that we can refer to the `move()` message that `cat1.move()` sends as `Cat.move()`, and we can refer to the `move()` message that `dog1.move()` sends as `Dog.move()`. Now when we make the `Cat` and `Dog` classes inherit from `Animal`, then when we do `Animal animal1 = new Cat(); animal1.move(); animal1 = new Dog(); animal1.move();`...

Comment: ...then the `move()` message that `animal1.move()` sends to the `Cat` object is the same as the `move()` message that `animal1.move()` sends to the `Dog` object, and to distinguish this `move()` message from the `Cat.move()` and `Dog.move()` messages, I would refer to it as `Animal.move()`. Now when we made the `Cat` and `Dog` classes inherit from `Animal`, this made each of the `Cat` and `Dog` objects able to understand two messages, the `Dog` objects can understand the `Animal.move()` and `Dog.move()` messages...

Comment: ...and the `Cat` objects can understand the `Animal.move()` and `Cat.move()` messages, the following example would send the two messages that the `Cat` objects can understand to a `Cat` object: `Cat cat1 = new Cat(); cat1.move(); Animal animal1 = cat1; animal1.move(); // cat1.move() sends the Cat.move() message to cat1 and animal1.move() sends the Animal.move() message to cat1`. Now if `Animal` was an `interface` then both the `Animal.move()` and  `Cat.move()` messages would have the same message handler, but if `Animal` was a concrete superclass...

Comment: ...then the `Animal.move()` message may have its own implementation (or it may not if the `Animal.move()` method was `virtual`). Am I correct?

Comment: @Tom You seem to be over-thinking this.  For the reason I described above about a message not depending upon the target object's type, the message itself does not belong to any one class or interface - it's just a message.  i.e. the same `move()` message may be defined on many different classes and interfaces, yet is still the same message.  Of course different classes may provide different *implementations* (Which I think is what you're getting at) but the message itself is defined only by its name and its input parameters (in this case, an empty parameter list).

Comment: If the message is only named `move()` as you say, then how do you explain what is happening here (assume that `Animal` is a superclass of `Cat` and `Animal` have a non-virtual method called `move()`): `Cat cat1 = new Cat(); cat1.move(); Animal animal1 = cat1; animal1.move();`, according to what you said, `cat1.move()` sends a message named `move()` to `cat1`, and `animal1.move()` also sends a message named `move()` to `cat1`...

Comment: ...now if what you said is true, then `cat1` would not know which of the two `move()` message handlers to invoke (because there is no way to distinguish between the two sent `move()` messages, since they both have the same name), but this isn't what happens, what happens is that the method `cat1.move()` causes one message handler to be invoked, and `animal1.move()` causes another message handler to be invoked!...

Comment: ...Can the explanation be that `cat1` is actually composed of two objects which are a `Cat` object and an `Animal` object, and each one of these two objects have its own `move()` message handler, and when we do `Cat cat1 = new Cat()` then `cat1` will point only to the `Cat` object (and so when we later do `cat1.move()`, then the `move()` message will be sent to the `Cat` object which only have one `move()` message handler that gets invoked)...

Comment: ...and when we do `Animal animal1 = cat1` then `animal1` will point only to the `Animal` object (and so when we later do `animal1.move()`, then the `move()` message will be sent to the `Animal` object which only have one `move()` message handler that gets invoked)?

Comment: @Tom That's the difference between static-binding and dynamic-binding. In a static-binding scenario, the message is tied to a method implementation and class type at compile-time. In a dynamic-binding scenario such as messaging an object via a common interface, the object type and method implementation are unknown until runtime.  However, in both cases, the message is just a method name and parameters. Also this topic is straying from the original question and there are already too many comments here so i'd strongly recommend raising a new language-specific question to continue.

Answer (score 0):

## Conceptually Correct - at a very High Level.

Technically incorrect though. The message isn't sent to an Interface and then on forwarded to the instance.

What actually happens is that `Animal` establishes a protocol of behaviours. This protocol is filled in by implementations such as `Dog`, and this protocol is then used by callers to find the correct behaviour for the given implementation.

As such `Dog` implements its version of `makeSound` to make a barking noise. It publishes this behaviour as appropriate to the `Animal` protocol so that users of `Animal` can find this barking version of `makeSound`.

When the caller holding `Animal a` then makes a call `a.makeSound()`. The caller knowing about `Animal`s follows the protocol and gets the behaviour to call. In this case its `Dog.makeSound()`. It then calls this `Dog` implementation directly.

Comment: Interesting. But since protocols are not the most obvious and unambiguous concept of OOP, doesn't this answer risk to transform the interrogations PO has about interfaces to interrogations about protocols?